# Charging lead-acid batteries via a boost converter. Are my calculations right?

Tags: boost, charge, lead-acid, buck-boost

I want to charge my two lead-acid batteries connected in series to a stair-case lift. I do not have a proper charger *(don't have ebay/amazon here)* but I do have a **19V, 3A** laptop charger (SMPS). I also have to use something else than a typical charger because there is a **2-3V voltage drop** from the supply to the batteries (was bigger).

I plan to buy a boost converter (a 600W one because that's what I found in my neighbourhood: [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUpJs6Z41YM&t=219s)) and charge the batteries with the help of that step-up converter (and the protective diode).

Is the following math right? *(without the diode voltage drop)*

[image]

The batteries are 12V, 7Ah lead-acid and I will limit the current to 10% of the capacity. What do you think?

*L.E.:*

- *the boost converter has constant voltage regulation and current limiting capabilites*
- *the batteries will be continuously standby charged (with float voltage) and will be lightly used*

Comment: A proper battery charger costs almost nothing.   I understand you don't WANT to buy one, but if you don't charge these right, you'll be buying new batteries - which almost surely will be WAY more cost than a new charger!!!!!!   There are dozens of  sub $25  24V chargers available on Amazon/Ebay/Etc....

Comment: @KyleB you are perfectly right but in my country I don't have access to ebay/amazon and the bill would be more costly than buying a boost converter (also, I must admit that I don't trust the cheap things that I can find on some sites). I'll wait though until someone says that my calculations are ok.

Comment: Ahh  Yeah that can make things tough in some countries.   Can you DISCONNECT the batteries and charge them with standard 12V charger??    If you try to series-charge two lead acid batteries, and they're not very well 'balanced', you'll kill one of the cells.   Many systems will operate in series, but then charge in  parallel to avoid that.     Anyhow --- Does this boost-converter have an adjustable voltage output???     BTW, many laptop chargers are expecting a Li-Ion battery and will halt if they don't find one - So it may not work AT ALL

Comment: @KyleB sadly I can't do that because the equipment is in someone's house and I can't visit them very often :). Yes, it does, I edited the post.

Comment: Dude....   IMO  (and only MY opinion), if this is going is SOMEBODY ELSE'S house, you HAVE to do it right.   Even if that means sourcing something that is a pain to source.  Leaving a contraption like this in the hands of somebody who doesn't know what they're doing is asking for trouble.   You don't wanna be responsible for exploding batteries, fires, electrocution, etc....   Do it with properly engineered and safely designed equipment or don't do it.   (IMO again....)

Comment: Your calculations are fine. Measure the voltage of each battery if you have access and check that they are balanced. One caveat with your setup would be if the battery voltage is <19 V, at which point your boost converter can’t regulate and your laptop charger won’t be happy. How will you limit the current?

Comment: @KyleB Laptop chargers are not chargers, they are just power supplies. The charging circuitry for batteries is inside the laptop. Just like your mobile charger is just a 5V power supply, the battery charger is inside the phone. As long as you don't exceed the current rating, and stay within reasonable load current changes, the laptop supply can power custom circuitry.

Comment: @winny the batteries will be continuously standby charged (with float voltage) and will be lightly used

Comment: @Justme   No they're not.   Some maybe, but many/most have digital sensing to determine whats at the other end.   Try plugging a Dell charger into an HP laptop and see what happens.    Manufacturers will say it's for safety and it is, but it's also to ensure you buy THEIR stuff later.

Comment: @KyleB I do this without asking a penny, it's for a good cause. Also, I also have to use something like this because there is a 2-3V voltage drop from the supply to the batteries (was bigger).

Comment: @KyleB Of course they are manufacturer specific, but what is common is that they just tell the laptop how much power or current is available from the power brick as they sell different supplies. It does not change the fact that they are power supplies and the charger that takes in 19V is inside the laptop. They are definitely not chargers, at least most of them are not.

Comment: @Justme  You may be right.  I've only my experience to go on, and the ones I've cut up def have communication going on.  But I am not wrong that this is a "bad idea" to put in somebody elses house.  OP should do it right or not do it - The road to hell is paved with good intentions they say....

Comment: @KyleB I have to agree with you on that one.

Comment: Then it’s probably fine except for edge cases like power loss, batteries get depleted, power comes back, charger goes into OCP hiccup and won’t recover.

Comment: Add....  The user will 100% inadvertently leave the charger on over & over & over, and overcharge the batteries many times until they are ruined.  Because THATS WHAT PEOPLE DO!!!   Get an automatic charger or be prepared to buy new batteries in a couple months....

Comment: @KyleB please read https://www.power-sonic.com/blog/how-to-charge-a-lead-acid-battery/ about standby charging.

Comment: @tibi10   My friend, I know all that.   My current employment, our product line uses AGM Lead Acid batteries.   I'm responsible for hundreds of millions of dollars of consumer-destined products.  I deal with the CPSC regularly, UL, etc... you name it.   I'm a degreed EE with 25 years experience - I've forgotten more than most people will ever know about electronics - And all that said - If I were in the same situation, with all my experience, I still wouldn't build & put that into service.  You're putting property and people at risk unnecessarily.

Comment: BTW, switching regulators are often unstable at very low loads (i.e. 'float voltage')  ....  especially cheap ones.